# derivative of $ g(z^2+1)$ where $g(z)=\ln r+i\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis

Knowing that

$$\begin{aligned}  
g(z)=\ln r+i \theta && (r>0,0 < \theta < 2\pi)
\end{aligned}$$

is analytic in the indicated domain def with derivative $g'(z)=\frac{1}{z}$

show that the composite function $G(z)=g(z^2+1)$ is analytic in the quadrant $x>0$, $y>0$ with derivative

$$G'(z)=\frac{2z}{z^2+1}$$

suggestion observe that $\Im(z^2+1)>0$ when $x>0,y>0$

$$G'(z)=g'(z^2+1)2z=\frac{1}{z^2+1}2z$$

Have trouble seeing why $x>0$, $y>0$. Guessing I am having trouble putting $z^2+1=r^2 e^{\theta i 2}+1 =r^2 e^{\theta i 2}+e^{i\theta\pi/2}$ in polar form $re^{\theta i}$.

Comment: I am also studying complex analysis from brown and churchill...but this problem has me perplexed. Can you tell me whether this problem tells us to show that the function is analytic in the quadrant x>0,y>0 . Or does this problem wants us to show that the first quadrant is the only region where it is analytic?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $z_0=x_0+iy_0$ is in the open first quadrant then $z_0^2$ is in the upper half-plane $H$, and so is $z_0^2+1$. It follows that $z_0^2+1$ is in the domain of $g$, as declared, so that $G(z):=g(z^2+1)$ is well defined and analytic in a neighborhood of $z_0$. The chain rule then gives the formula for $G'(z)$ you obtained.